# Usage of auto in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

When I use `auto` to deduce a pointer type, I found a weird phenomenon. My code is like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i = 100;
    auto p1 = &i;
    auto *p2 = &i;

    cout << *p1 << " " << *p2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

After compiling and executing, we can find that the result of `*p1` and `*p2` is the same, both 100. This means `p1` and `p2` are both a pointer object which points to an `int` object.

```
[user@host ~]$ ./test 
100 100
```

Is there any difference between these two statements which define `p1` and `p2`?

Comment: Of course, what else could possibly happen? If p1 and p2 were not both pointers then you couldn't initialize them with `&i`.  Maybe you should write (and think) in terms of `auto* p2` not `auto *p2` to make it clear that that `p2` is a variable of a pointer type, with the pointed-to type automatically deduced by the compiler.

Comment: `auto* p2 = init()` enforces raw pointer type. Might be useful if e.g. someday `init()` is refactored to return `shared_ptr<T>` and instead of copying this value and keeping that `T` in memory, you get a compilation error and have a chance to decide whether to use `shared_ptr<T>`, `weak_ptr<T>`, or `T&`.

Comment: This is why `auto` is both magical and potentially confusing.

Answer (score 84):

The difference is that in the first case auto is deduced to `int*` while in the second case auto is deduced to `int`, which results in both `p1` and `p2` being of type `int*`. 
The type deduction mechanism for auto is equivalent to that of template arguments. The type deduction in your example is therefore similar to

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T p1);

template<typename T>
void bar(T* p2);

int main()
{
    int i;
    foo(&i);
    bar(&i);
}
```

where both functions are instantiated as type void(int*) but in the first case `T` is deduced to `int*` while in the second case `T` has type `int`.

Comment: upvoted for laying out the equivalent template instantiation

Answer (score 20):

`auto` specifier used in declarations of variables, deduces its type
   with the same rules as used in **[template argument
   deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction)**.

Consider your first example (i.e., `auto p1 = &i;`). The type of
   `auto` specifier is deduced as follows:

1. `auto` is replaced with an    imaginary type template parameter (e.g., `U p1 = &i;`).
2. `&i` type is `int*`, thus with no surprises and according to template deduction rules `U` is deduced to `int*`.

Now consider your second example (i.e., `auto *p2 = &i`).

1. Again `auto` is replaced with an imaginary type template parameter (e.g., `U* p1 = &i;`).
2. `&i` type is `int*`, thus according to template deduction rules `U` is deduced to `int`.

As such, in `auto *p2 = &i;` the placeholder type `auto` will correctly be deduced as `int` and not as `int*`, that would result in `p2` being of type `int**`, as you might have expected.

Comment: +1 for mentioning template argument deduction rule. However, as a note, `auto` type deduction has one small difference from template type deduction (see Meyers' Effective Modern C++), although I don't remember the details.

Comment: The difference is due to curly brace initializer lists: auto x = {1,2,3}. Cited from Scott Meyers book (Effective modern c++): "auto type deduction is usually the same as template type deduction, but auto type deduction assumes that a braced initializer represents a std::initializer_list, and template type deduction doesn’t.".